# Populating an array with all combinations

Tags: c#, enums, combinations

Given an enum, I was wondering how to populate a jagged array so that each inner array contains a combination of the enum values (7 values in the enum, 6 slots in the inner arrays, repeats allowed), and the outer array contains each possible combination (not permutation; Red Red Red Red Red Orange and Red Red Red Red Orange Red are the same element).

A multi-dimensional array would also work, though a jagged array would seem more applicable given the real-world problem. I'm just having trouble figuring out how the loop to populate it would be written.

The language is C#.  I am hoping populate it in a way that sorts the results in order from "highest" to "lowest" value, (starting with Red Red Red Red Red Red, then Red Red Red Red Red Orange, etc.).  This is the enum:

```
public enum OrderedColors
{
    Colorless,
    Purple,
    Blue,
    Green,
    Yellow,
    Orange,
    Red
}
```

Comment: About avoiding same selections in different order: Assign a number to each color, so that adding them add for each combination will result in the same resulting number irrespective of the order of the elements. This way, you can quickly check if you have a particular combination (in a different order) already processed and achieve sorting. For 6 slots (and up to 9 slots), you could for example choose numbers like: ColorLess = 1, Purple = 10, Blue = 100, Green = 1000, etc...

Comment: @elgonzo A good algorithm for this shouldn't even risk generating the same combination twice.

Comment: @Rawling, i don't disagree, but you should perhaps explain a better approach if you already put the finger on it ;)

Comment: @Rawling, actually, you triggered a nerve of me. Looking at the answers given here, i can't help but thinking that there is a faster method to avoid all the juggling with lists/collections/enumerators by leveraging the fact that such enum values can be represented as number.

Comment: @elgonzo You're right, there's a theme of "generate all the slightly-smaller combinations, then stick this on the start", but I'm not sure how else I'd do it. I think Dennis is closest in this regard with what is essentially nested loops.

Comment: @Rawling, going with the number theme, it should be possible that when iterating over the colors for arrary index [pos+1] to check whether the currently iterated color is smaller than the one at array index [pos]. This should still allow repeating colors while still providing sorting without additional costs. (i hope ;) )

Comment: @Rawling, I think i need to back away from my first comment :) The approach is not that simple as i first thought. Yes, i made an implementation where the enum members are treated as numerals of a (7-digit) numerical system. The full range of that numerical system is traversed while skipping ranges with  permutations. This resulted in 2x performance compared to Oleksandr's answer. But frankly, it is an unreadable, unmaintainable mess of code. I feel slightly embarrassed. [Look here for the source code](http://pastebin.com/gRpGvEcq) and be shocked. (Sorry, no source comments.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with simple recursive function to make it scalable. It receives array of items to combine, number of items to select from array and start index in array where to seleft items from (default to 0). It recursifely selects first item at every allowed starting position and attaches all combinations of further elements to the right in the items array.

```
public static IEnumerable<T[]> BuildCombinations<T>(T[] items, int itemsCountInCombination, int startIndex = 0)
{
    if (itemsCountInCombination == 0)
    {
        yield return new T[0];
        yield break;
    }
    for (int i = startIndex; i < items.Length; i++)
    {
        foreach (var combination in BuildCombinations(items, itemsCountInCombination - 1, i))
        {
            var c = new T[itemsCountInCombination];
            c[0] = items[i];
            Array.Copy(combination, 0, c, 1, combination.Length);
            yield return c;
        }
    }
}


private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var c in BuildCombinations(Enum.GetValues(typeof (OrderedColors)).Cast<OrderedColors>().Reverse().ToArray(), 6))
    {
        foreach (var color in c)
        {
            Console.Write(color);
            Console.Write(" ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

It generates the expected 924 combinations with repetition of 6 elements out of 7 in 0,44ms. It's probably not the best possible performance and it uses more memory than possible, but it's very simple implementation and efficient enough for such number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

using LINQ:

```
OrderedColors[] colors = (OrderedColors[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(OrderedColors));

OrderedColors[][] matrix = (
    from a in colors
    from b in colors
    from c in colors
    from d in colors
    from e in colors
    from f in colors
    select new [] {a,b,c,d,e,f}
).ToArray();
```

If you want to make something that can generate combinations of any length, than you need something more complicated.

Edit: you can fix it by adding a where clause after each from:

```
OrderedColors[][] matrix = (
    from a in colors
    from b in colors
    where a<=b
    from c in colors
    where b<=c
    from d in colors
    where c<=d
    from e in colors
    where d<=e
    from f in colors
    where e<=f
    select new [] {a,b,c,d,e,f}
).ToArray();
```

Comment: Does it avoid permutations?

Comment: I forgot about that. No it doesn't. It creates an array of length 117649

Comment: You generate 100 000+ permutations and then select only 924 correct of them! Awfully inefficient solution

Answer (score 0):

I found this question interesting and continued working on a solution... here you go...

Use the code like this...

```
    var example = new[] { 
        OrderedColors.Red, OrderedColors.Orange, OrderedColors.Yellow, 
        OrderedColors.Green, OrderedColors.Blue, OrderedColors.Purple, 
        OrderedColors.Colorless };
    var combinations = example.CombinationsWithRepetition(6);
```

Which yields 924 results as expected and doesn't do any unecessary calculations or copying.  Below are the actual methods.

```
    public static IEnumerable<IList<T>> CombinationsWithRepetition<T>
        (this IEnumerable<T> input, int take) where T : new()
    {
        var items = input.ToList();
        return CombinationsWithRepetition(items, null, take, 0, 0);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<IList<T>> CombinationsWithRepetition<T>
        (List<T> allItems, IList<T> thisSequence, int maxLength, 
        int currentLength, int currentIndex)
    {
        if (maxLength == 0)
            yield return new List<T>();
        for (var index = currentIndex; index < allItems.Count; index++)
        {
            var nextSequence = thisSequence == null ? new List<T>() : 
                  thisSequence.ToList();
            nextSequence.Add(allItems[index]);
            if (currentLength + 1 == maxLength)
            {
                yield return nextSequence;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var sequence in CombinationsWithRepetition(allItems, 
                   nextSequence, maxLength, currentLength + 1, index))
                {
                    yield return sequence;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Enjoy!   It was fun writing it.